# Run scheduled and automated Orange worklow

Tags: python, orange

How can I schedule the execution of a workflow in orange canvas?

For example, I have a predictive model that use tweets collected with Twitter Widget ( text analysis Add-on) and then predict some behaviour to send alerts with Python bot (Python Widget). I need this prediction process to run automatically daily.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try it to use some scheduler (on Linux I would use `cron`) and schedule it to run `orange-canvas` with your workflow (pass the file as an argument).

If you end your python script with `sys.exit()` it will also close Orange after this.

I think there is no way to hide the Orange canvas while the workflow is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marko... I am going try this suggestion in my case in Windows...

Comment: Unfortunately, the Orange Twitter widget does not automatically update the search when opening the model, so it does not meet the goal of refreshing the Tweets that I want to process every time

Comment: Sorry that it did not work. Perhaps open an issue in https://github.com/biolab/orange3-text regarding tweets refresh.